# Button doesnt work on jquery when Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code on my jquery

```
 participantText += '<div class="wrap_col td7"><input type="image" src="/pc/images/callgray.png" style="vertical-align: middle" class="actionInvite"></div>';
```

This is the action of class actionInvite

```
$(".actionInvite").click(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
});
```

but when i click the button it doesn't alert "Hello World".

It's just reload the page.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '.actionInvite', function(){...`

Comment: use delegate function `$(".wrap_col").on('click', '.actionInvite', function(){`

Comment: @TamilSelvan `.wrap_col` is added dynamically too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You html is dynamically assigned.

For dynamic content

Try like this

```
$(document).on("click",".actionInvite",function(){
    alert("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `image` input type is actually a [submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image#simple_input_image_example) (thus the reload). If you must use it, then you need to do this on your class or somewhere in your form submit event handler:

```
$(".actionInvite").closest('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("Hello World");
});
```

With html5 and modern CSS, I'd totally forgotten that input type actually exists. I'm sure a cleaner, better solution is out there on the horizon of your mind.

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kennasoft/ukpf26fc/) for it.